# Socket.IO not firing client side events when cutting internet connection

Tags: socket.io

I am using socket.io with js client side like so:

```
this.connect = function(roomname) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if(self.isConnected)        {
      deferred.$$reject('already connected');
      return deferred.promise;
    }
    self.isConnected = true;
    connectedRoom = roomName;

    socket = io('', {
      query: 'roomname=' + roomname
    });
    socket.on('connect', function() {
      console.log('socket client connected ' + socket.id);
      $rootScope.$broadcast('socketsConnected');

      socket.emit('room', roomName, function() {
        deferred.resolve();
      });
    });
    socket.on('reconnect', function() {
      self.isConnected = true;
      console.log('socket client reconnecting ' + socket.id);
    });
    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
      self.isConnected = false;
      console.log('socket client disconnecting ' + socket.id);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
  }
```

When I switch off the server, the `disconnect` event fired as expected. When I switch the server back on, `reconnect` is fired as expected.

However if I switch of my wi-fi, the `disconnect` event never fires (I have left it several minutes).

When I switch the wi-fi back on the `reconnect` event does not fire, it does however seem to re-establish a connection as the messages will then emit and receive correctly.

How can I get these events to fire on losing wi-fi?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I've had a long day. In case anyone is as much of an idiot as I am, my server was on the same machine as my client so cutting the wi-fi had zero effect!

Comment: That's a good one.  That's when you know it's really time to take a break from programming and go do something else for awhile.